# НередкИ или нерЕдки?

Tags: фонетика

Что-то меня замкнуло. Как правильно поставить ударение: нередкИ или нерЕдки?
Спасибо

Answer (score 6, accepted):

У Аванесова рЕдки,  допустимо редкИ.  Но этому словарю уж лет 30. Казалось бы , допустимое у Аванесова уже могло бы и равноправным вариантом стать. И так действительно отмечено в орфографическом словаре Лопатина. А вот Зарва в "Русском словесном ударении" более категоричен, там только рЕдки.

Вообще заметила на многих двусложных словах. Было ударение на первом слоге. Начало перемещаться на второй. Вроде и словари зафиксировали как допустимое или равноправное с предыдущим вариантом. И пошло: как признак грамотности что ли, многие ведущие, дикторы заговорили именно по старой норме. Например,   у дверИ -у двЕри. Сейчас и не вспомню еще, но именно в двусложных словах так происходит.

Comment: Плавающие ударения - большое достоинство русского языка.  
"И горьки мне, горьки твои упреки..."

Answer (score 0):

НередкА, нерЕдко, нерЕдки и допуст. нередкИ. 
(Т.Ф. Иванова. "Новый орфоэпический словарь русского языка" 2008)